# Make all fragments above Banner Ad

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, admob, banner

I have 3 `Fragments`in the `MainActivity` where they are all showing, in the MainActivity layout I have a Banner Ad below a progress bar (both placed at the bottom), So what I want is the all fragment is placed above the banner and the progress bar, is there any solution ??

this is the full activity_main layout (with the solution I describe in the comments section):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">



        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary_color"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/more_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/thumbsuo" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                style="@style/CategoryTab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                />


                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBarParent"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"

                    />

                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">

                </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/text_drawer_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/text_drawer_color"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this the full layout of the fragment :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/tan_background"
>



<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"

    >

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    android:divider="@color/tan_background"
    android:dividerHeight="8dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

  />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you posted more code, I see it's even easier then I thought. You don't need `RelativeLayout` at all. You can use single `LinearLayout`, and have your ViewPager set to have a weight of 1, so it fills the empty space. Here is the code (not tested, so may have typos).

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/more_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/thumbsuo"

        />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/CategoryTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarParent"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"

    />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/text_drawer_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/text_drawer_color"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your aswer , but the problem is that the content view which is a listview is defined in another layout and the adView and progressBarParent are defined in the mainActivity layout ,so I can't set the content view above the progressbarparent and adView .

Comment: @Karim Can you post a little more code. Usually you add a contentView to the Activity, and then you use the FragmentManager to insert the Fragment in place of that View. What the Fragment is, makes no difference.

Comment: no need , I ended up by editing the fragments layout by adding an empty layout at the bottom with the same banner size so when they are added to the main activity they will be automatically above the banner .

Comment: @karim That is bad design, that will come back to haunt you.

Comment: why it is bad design ?? I didn't found any other solution anyway , yours doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @karim Bad design because you are relying that any changes to the Activity will also be copied to all Fragments. Any changes in Fragments, will require to be syncronized with Activity. There is no reason a layout like I suggested shouldn't work. It would have been helpful if you had posted the full layout.

Comment: I added the full layout , but How I will put the fragment above the (banner and the progressbar ) if they are in difined in different layouts ??

Comment: yeah it work perfectly thanks bro , but now after adding the coordinator layout and appbar , the toolbar dosn't hide when I roll down , I think the linear layout blocks the coordinatorlayout ,any suggestions for that ??

Comment: Accept the answer, and post a new question

Comment: I accept it bro , now is it possible to do it with the coordinator layout ??

Comment: @karim Please start a new question, post the code exactly as it is now, and explain what the issue is.